# App crashes on samsung A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x2 in tid 6880

Tags: android

The app crashes without a particular reason and I'm unable to narrow down to the root cause. This issue, seems to only happen on samsung 8.0+ devices: S8,S9,etc..
Here I'm adding the stack trace below.  I'm kinda wondering what is libruntimecore.so. Help me to fix this, I'm clueless.

P.S I'm not using any NDK in the application

**Stacktrace:**

```
    2019-08-31 14:35:46.898 3926-4099/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1
2019-08-31 14:35:50.661 3926-4409/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 5138 [2019-08-31 14:35:50.660] FD count : 812
2019-08-31 14:35:55.110 6674-6880/com.example.administrator.cookapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x2 in tid 6880 (trator.cookapp), pid 6674 (trator.cookapp)
2019-08-31 14:35:55.215 7848-7848/? E/DEBUG: failed to readlink /proc/6880/fd/65: No such file or directory
2019-08-31 14:35:55.216 7848-7848/? E/DEBUG: failed to readlink /proc/6880/fd/89: No such file or directory
2019-08-31 14:35:55.217 7848-7848/? E/DEBUG: failed to readlink /proc/6880/fd/91: No such file or directory
2019-08-31 14:35:55.440 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2019-08-31 14:35:55.440 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/greatltexx/greatlte:9/PPR1.180610.011/N950FXXS7DSG1:user/release-keys'
2019-08-31 14:35:55.440 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '9'
2019-08-31 14:35:55.440 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2019-08-31 14:35:55.440 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG: pid: 6674, tid: 6880, name: trator.cookapp  >>> com.example.administrator.cookapp <<<
2019-08-31 14:35:55.441 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x2
2019-08-31 14:35:55.441 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2019-08-31 14:35:55.441 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     r0  e433dfe0  r1  bf9fa74c  r2  00000036  r3  00000000
2019-08-31 14:35:55.441 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     r4  c6469ca0  r5  00000003  r6  00000000  r7  00000036
2019-08-31 14:35:55.441 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     r8  00000036  r9  00000014  r10 00000002  r11 00000001
2019-08-31 14:35:55.441 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     ip  c41549a5  sp  c39ca848  lr  c514e8ef  pc  00000002
2019-08-31 14:35:55.454 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-08-31 14:35:55.454 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000002  <unknown>
2019-08-31 14:35:55.454 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 013c38ed  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.454 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 013d2b05  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.454 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 013d2d5d  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.454 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 013c4ad3  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.454 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 013c595b  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.454 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 013c5b1b  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.454 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 013c5b3b  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.454 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00d1520b  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.454 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00cf42b9  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00c88251  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00c88905  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00c889df  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 00c8b76f  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 00c71633  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 00c71a2d  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00c71fe7  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 00c72051  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 0151908d  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 00c729eb  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 015189ff  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 010fbc4b  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.455 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 01105fed  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.456 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 011064ff  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.456 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 01106791  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.456 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 011060ff  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.456 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 015847ef  /data/app/com.example.administrator.cookapp-aPyol1VDdufWY_v5qLWWtw==/lib/arm/libruntimecore.so
2019-08-31 14:35:55.456 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 00064899  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+140)
2019-08-31 14:35:55.456 7848-7848/? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 0001e329  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+24)
2019-08-31 14:35:56.992 3926-4099/? E/MotionRecognitionService: handleMessage: event 200 value : 1
2019-08-31 14:35:58.447 3551-3551/? E//system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
2019-08-31 14:35:58.468 3469-3469/? E/audit: type=1701 audit(1567247758.457:4681): auid=4294967295 uid=10329 gid=10329 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c73,c257,c512,c768 pid=6674 comm="trator.cookapp" exe="/system/bin/app_process32" sig=11
2019-08-31 14:35:58.527 3378-3378/? E/lmkd: Error writing /proc/6674/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2019-08-31 14:35:58.528 7857-7857/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2019-08-31 14:35:58.528 7857-7857/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2019-08-31 14:35:58.537 7857-7857/? E/ng.android.loo: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2019-08-31 14:35:58.576 3926-3969/? E/WindowManager: RemoteException occurs on reporting focusChanged, w=Window{3127fcd u0 com.example.administrator.cookapp/com.fidelity.cookapp.activities.MainActivity}
    android.os.DeadObjectException
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1143)
        at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.windowFocusChanged(IWindow.java:500)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowState.reportFocusChangedSerialized(WindowState.java:3913)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:5441)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
```

Comment: any solution for this issue?